# How do I force the download of Windows modules

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, electron

I am in a unique situation where I can run `npm install` only on a linux based machine even though I plan to run my electron/node application on an offline Windows machine.

So, is there a way to tell `npm` to perform an install and "trick" it to `npm install` the windows version of each module?

I understand most modules are based on javascript and are not native, but a few are dependent on operating system, such as electron itself.

Perhaps I could modify any header information `npm` sends out which tells the servers which operating system I am running?

Comment: Just run `npm install` again on the Windows machine.

Comment: I can't run `npm install` on windows due to some very heavy proxy/blocking issues. I can on Linux though... :\

Comment: No; I mean run `npm install` in the downloaded modules to run their install scripts.

Comment: Well all that does is try to re-download all the elements of the module, which the proxy just blocks.

Answer (score 0):

> So, is there a way to tell npm to perform an install and "trick" it to
>   npm install the windows version of each module?

No.  If you want NPM to install for windows, then you have to run NPM on windows.

For pure Javascript modules, you could "probably" install for Linux and then just copy the directories over to windows, but you'd have to know that these were pure Javascript modules that contained no native code and did not use any binaries or compile any native code and copying directories behind the back of NPM is asking for it to be confused about what you have.

It sounds like perhaps you should explore fixing whatever issue is keeping you from running NPM on your windows box directly.